# Use py-corenlp to parse a string with many sentences

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a question when i use py-corenlp to parse a string with many sentences

Python output image

[image]

the output show that it just parses first sentences,and skip next two sentences

but when i use CoreNLP server to parse my sentence.It automatically divide the line into three sentences and parse them individually.

Correct result image

[image]

So,how to solve this problem ? i really appreciate your help.

Comment: what is `len(output['sentences'])` in your python example? Presumably, it should be 3 in normal operation.

Comment: Write the code out, don't paste screenshots... Otherwise its' really hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the `output['sentences']` list:

```
text=‘This is it, kid. This is our chance. When you got a chance, you better take it.’

output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={‘annotators’: ‘tokenize,ssplit,lemma,pos,depparse,parse’, ‘outputFormat’: ‘json’})

for sent in output[‘sentences’]:
    print(sent[‘parse’])
```

Alternatively, you can use the CoreNLP API in NLTK, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/corenlp.py#L343